# "On its own" translation

Tags: traduction

How would I say on its own/on their own in the following context: "one of these factors on its own wouldn't have led to this decision, but all factors combined does"?

I'm thinking of something along the lines of "un de ces facteurs sur eux-mêmes", but it feels a bit awkward (or even just wrong).

Comment: "Un de ces facteurs, seul, ne..." is the easiest way to translate it. "Sur eux-mêmes" would be the translation of "on/onto themselves." On another note, it should be "on *its* own", so "seul" and not "seuls", because out of all the factors, only one of them by itself can't...

Answer (score 2):

I would have translate by :

> Seul, aucun de ces facteurs n'aurait mené à cette décision.

or more literally

> Un de ces facteurs par lui même n'aurait pas mené à cette décision, mais tous les facteurs combinés l'ont fait.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Edit done, thanks !

Comment: de lui même ou à lui seul serait un peu plus joli je pense

Comment: @JulianColin Pour la partie jolie, cf. ma première traduction, une traduction littérale l'est rarement.

Answer (score 2):

I usually translate "on its own" by *de lui même* but here *à lui seul* would better fit:

> L'un de ces facteurs n'aurait pas, à lui seul, conduit à cette décision mais la combinaison de tous les facteurs, si.